# call class with optional arguments

Tags: javascript

I have a class with 4 property which 2 of them is optional, I have problem with the order of argument as if one of them missed value will replace for wrong attribute. see the code:

```
class Book{
   constructor(name, author, bookURL, publishDate){
   this.name = name;
   this.author = author;
   this.bookURL = bookURL;
   this.publishDate = publishDate;

   }
}
```

here the name and author are required but bookURL and publishDate is optional. so for example if we call a class without URL but with publish date the date will assigned for the bookURL.

```
new Book(
  "The Unhoneymooners",
  "Christina Lauren",
  "2019"
)
```

This will output:

```
Book {
 name: 'The Unhoneymooners',
 author:
  'Christina Lauren',
 bookURL:
  '2019' }
```

here it expected to set bookURL to undefined and publishDate to 2019. I hope you understand the problem here. Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the constructor accept a single argument instead, a destructured object:

```
constructor({name, author, bookURL, publishDate}) {
```

So you can pass

```
new Book({
  name: "The Unhoneymooners",
  author: "Christina Lauren",
  publishDate: "2019"
})
```